# What is the name of the crinkly plastic used in clear parts of envelopes?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, plastics

I've always wondered what it is, as it makes a lot of noise on being deformed. No other common plastic that I've come across has quite the same properties.

Comment: In the old days it was cellophane, and may still be (or just generically called cellophane whether it is or is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more commonly referred to as 'envelope window film'. I've read somewhere that about 90% of all envelope window films are made from polystyrene, but sadly I cannot find the source at the moment. The remainder is made from polyester, polypropylene or [glassine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassine).

For examples see [this manufacturer](http://www.multi-plastics.com/europe-envelope-window-film/) or [this one](http://www.transilwrap.com/films-applications/folding-carton-envelope-windows/envelope-window-films). I'm not affiliated with either company, these are just the only ones I could find that provide specifications and proof my point.

Answer (score 4):

It usually is BOPS: Biaxially oriented polystyrene.

Comment: Yes I just took a look at an envelope... with IR spec. It's atactic polystyrene.